# How to improve the onChange attribute to effect the changes after browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I have a dynamic form which depending on the value in a pull down selection field will either show or hide a form fieldset.

> e.g. Do you wish to get a quote just now? [YES/NO]

This works fine the way it is at the moment however there is a limitation when the user refreshes the form and the value is still intact however the changes that should have made an effect on the document are not shown. i.e. it is reset to its original state

The only way to remedy this is to redo the selection in that form field i.e. (reclick Yes/No).

Is there anyway I can workaround this problem? Perhaps a seperate javascript that checks the value of that field?

How would you tackle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refresh reinitialises the page so will reset everything that the browser doesn't remember for you. The only way would be to store the value in a session/cookie and read it each time the page is loaded to check if the fieldset should be shown on hidden.

Comment: Why does it remember the values in my fields then when I hit refresh? Im using Firefox. If I do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) then it will reset the whole page and form.

Comment: Some of the modern browsers do, but not all. For example Chrome doesn't (my version anyway)